# Bootstrap Table GET JSON Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, bootstrap-table

So I am trying to make bootstrap table with search and sorting with the data coming from a GET calll

```
   <table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" data-search="true">
    <thead>
      <tr class="text-white clickable-row" bgcolor="#578ebe" >
        <th id="white-text"> # </th>
        <th id="white-text"> Name </th>
        <th id="white-text"> DBA </th>
        <th id="white-text"> Facility ID </th>
        <th id="white-text"> Active </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="hospital in hospital_filtered = hospitals">
        <td> <a ng-click="click(hospital)"> {{ hospital.hospital_id }} </td>
        <td> <a ng-click="click(hospital)"> {{ hospital.hospital_name }} </td>
        <td> <a ng-click="click(hospital)"> {{ hospital.hospital_dba }} </td>
        <td> <a ng-click="click(hospital)"> {{ hospital.facility_id }} </td>
        <td> <a ng-click="click(hospital)"> {{ hospital.active_flag }} </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Here is where I make the GET call from my API. The data is coming in, but the bootstrap table sorting and sort are not working. How do I populate bootstrap table with this call?

```
$http.get("/hospitals/all", {
          params: {authtoken: $rootScope.auth_token}}
        )
        .then(function(response) {
          // Request completed successfully
          //console.log(response);
          $scope.hospitals=response.data

        }, function(x) {
          // Request error
          console.log("Error");
        });
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

You're correctly fetching the data, but the iteration is wrong.

HTML:

```
<input ng-model="searchKeyword" type="text">
<table id="example" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover" data-search="true">
<thead>
  <tr class="text-white clickable-row" bgcolor="#578ebe" >
    <th id="white-text" ng-click="changeSort('hospital_id')"> # </th>
    <th id="white-text" ng-click="changeSort('hospital_name')"> Name </th>
    <th id="white-text" ng-click="changeSort('hospital_dba')"> DBA </th>
    <th id="white-text" ng-click="changeSort('facility_id')"> Facility ID </th>
    <th id="white-text" ng-click="changeSort('active_flag')"> Active </th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <tr ng-repeat="hospital in hospitals | filter: searchKeyword | orderBy: orderKeyword">
    <td> <a ng-click="click(hospital)"> {{ hospital.hospital_id }} </td>
    <td> <a ng-click="click(hospital)"> {{ hospital.hospital_name }} </td>
    <td> <a ng-click="click(hospital)"> {{ hospital.hospital_dba }} </td>
    <td> <a ng-click="click(hospital)"> {{ hospital.facility_id }} </td>
    <td> <a ng-click="click(hospital)"> {{ hospital.active_flag }} </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The Javascript part:

```
$scope.orderKeyword = 'hospital_name';
$scope.changeSort = function(sortAttr) {
  $scope.orderKeyword = sortAttr;
};
```

`filter: searchKeyword` will use the keyword typed into the additional input-field. This way you can basically "search" the table. The results that are left will then be ordered by (`orderBy`) the attribute-name that's stored inside `$scope.orderKeyword`. I initialized it with `hospital_name`.

You may add additional logic like how strict the filtering and which direction the sorting is supposed to be.

Here's the documentation for the two filters in question:

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter